# Create a node and add it as sibling node before another sibling with dynatree

Tags: dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I want to create programmatically a new node.
Then I want to add this before another node as sibling.

This code does not work:

```
var node = $("#TreeDiv").dynatree("getActiveNode");
var nextSiblingNode = node.getNextSibling();
var childNode = node.addChild({ title: response.title, key: response.unitId }, nextSiblingNode);
```

What do I wrong?

UPDATE:

Thats the exception I got with the above code:

```
Unhandled exception at line 4, column 20662 in http://localhost:1726/Scripts/jquery.dynatree.min.js

0x800a139e - runtime error in JavaScript: <beforeNode> must be a child of <this>
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: I updated my question with the error message.

Comment: @socialrel8 Any idea about the error message?

Comment: Look's like that first parameter of addChild is expecting an array - after looking at the dynatree source code.

Comment: an array or a javascipt object I have read. So I do not understand whats wrong. I even found the exception thrown in the internal addChild function: var iBefore = $.inArray(beforeNode, this.childList);
   if( iBefore < 0 ){
    throw "<beforeNode> must be a child of <this>";
   } but that does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

After creating the node as a child I had to move the node and it worked... of course the code still needs some null checks ;-)

```
var newNode = { title: response.title, key: response.unitId };
var activeNode = $("#TreeDiv").dynatree("getActiveNode");
var nextSiblingNode = activeNode.getNextSibling();
if (nextSiblingNode != null) {
    newNode = activeNode.addChild(newNode);
    newNode.move(nextSiblingNode, 'before');
}
else
{                      
    var parentNode = activeNode.getParent();
    newNode = parentNode.addChild(newNode);
}
newNode.activate(true);
newNode.focus(true);
```